# Order by on aggregated column typeorm

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have two tables: `user` and `activity` with `@OneToMany` relationship.

I have to write a query that will count activity for user and return it with sort available. I do not know how it will be sorted, so, I have to enable sort on all fields, inclusive `activityCount`.

I tried to do this with `loadRelationCountAndMap` something like this

```
async getUsersAndCount(
    skip: number,
    limit: number,
    orderBy: string,
    orderOptions: OrderByOptions,
    query?: [string, ObjectLiteral][]
): Promise<[User[], number]> {
    const initialQuery =  this.createInitialQuery();

    if (query && query.length > 0) {
        query.forEach(q => initialQuery.andWhere(q[0], q[1]));
    }

    return await initialQuery.orderBy(orderBy, orderOptions)
        .offset(skip)
        .limit(limit)
        .printSql()
        .getManyAndCount();
}

private createInitialQuery(): SelectQueryBuilder<User> {
    return this.createQueryBuilder('user')
        .loadRelationCountAndMap('activityCount', 'user.activity', 'activityCount')
        .where('user.status = 1')
        .addGroupBy('user.id');
```

But I cannot order by `activityCount` field.

Then I tried to use subQuery, but it cannot create query that will join on activity table by userId.

Then I tried to use plain SQL query like this:

```
await this.query(
        'SELECT u."id"                AS "user_id",\n' +
        '       u."telegram_id"       AS "user_telegram_id",\n' +
        '       u."telegram_username" AS "user_telegram_username",\n' +
        '       COUNT(a.id)           AS activityCount\n' +
        'FROM "user" u\n' +
        'INNER JOIN activity a ON a."userId" = u.id\n' +
        'WHERE u."status" = 1\n' +
        'GROUP BY u."id"\n' +
        `ORDER BY $1 $2\n` +
        `OFFSET $3\n` +
        `LIMIT $4`);
```

with parameters order by, order direction, limit and offset, but typeorm didn't fill these parameters and I got `syntax error near $2`.

I can concatenate strings to fill parameters, but this will be soo bad way.

Also I can solve this problem using `VIEW`, but maybe there is another way?